# Calling a stylesheet when you are having a hosted site

Tags: css, node.js, localhost

So I've built a site in my directory and it can call all the stylesheets I made up just fine but when I create a local host it posts the html without any of the stylesheet. So the node would look like this

```
app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log("App listening on PORT " + PORT);
});
```

And my html like this

```
<head><link href="custome.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
<body> /snip </body>
```

So when ever I open up the local host at PORT it's blank.

Comment: did you define the static directory for express correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You should serve static files. You should give more detail about the issue.

If you're using something like express.js, you can do something like this;

```
const fs = require('fs');

app.get('/custome.css', function (req, res) {
    res.send(fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/custome.css'));
});
```

Comment: Oh now I feel silly. right now it looks like
{app.get("/", function(request, result) {
  result.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/../index.html"));
}